# Asynchronous Socket Server listening more than one address

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I need an asynchronous socket server that listens to more than one IP addresses. Basically what I want to do is to convert this loop to multiple addresses:

```
        while (true) {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            allDone.Reset();

            // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
            listener.BeginAccept( 
                new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                listener );

            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            allDone.WaitOne();
        }
```

In C I could handle it with WSAAsyncSelect and FD_ACCEPT messages, or I could use IO Completion ports, but in C# I'm lost, and maybe I'm not asking the right questions to Google, since I haven't found any thing helpful. Please help!!

This code was copied form the example I'm basing my efforts on, you can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you what you are asking is to accept multiple connections without the loop?

The trick is to use the call BeginAccept from within the callback.

Something like the following:

```
StartListening(){
  listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
  listener.Listen(100);
  GetNewConnection(listener);
}

private GetNewConnection (Socket listener){
  Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
  listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnNewConnection),
                       listener);
}

private OnNewConnection(IAsyncResult ar){
  Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
  Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
  GetNewConnection(listener);
  //... 
}
```

Handler is the socket to the remote IP, which there can be many of.

Edit: You can create of course call `GetNewConnection` with however many different listeners you want, if they need to bind to other addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `async` method using `Task.Factory.FromAsync` and then use that method to create all your connection tasks and then initiate them all in a loop and then call `Task.WaitAll` to wait for all the connections to be established. Note that `Task.WaitAll` is a blocking call, use `Task.WhenAll` if you want an asynchronous call.

so maybe something like this will do the job (untested, but compiles)

```
public static void Connect(List<IPAddress> ipAddresses) 
{
    var listeners = new List<Socket>();
    var tasks = new List<Task<Socket>>();

    foreach (var ipAddress in ipAddresses)
    {
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
        listeners.Add(listener);        
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);   

        tasks.Add(AcceptTaskAsync(listener));
    }   

    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}

public static async Task<Socket> AcceptTaskAsync(Socket listener)
{
    return await Task<Socket>.Factory.FromAsync(listener.BeginAccept, listener.EndAccept, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach);
}
```